# Autofill with VBA in this specific flow

Tags: excel, vba

Please i have this issue and i am trying to achieve a solution using vba.

```
So cell 
A1 has value John
A2-A3 blank
A4 has value Mary
A5-A9 blank
A10 has value Mike
A11-A14 blank
And A15 has value David
```

I wanna autofill only the blank spaces in the column A, like so:
A2-A3 the blanks will be filled with John
A5-A9 will be filled with Mary
A11-A14 with Mike.

So technically, I am auto filling the blank cells with the value from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One version to do this is:

```
Sub Autofill1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set your worksheet name
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row

For i = 1 To lrow 'Loop from 1st row to last row
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "" Then 'If the cell value is blank then...
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value '.. copy the value from previous cell above
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Another version is:

```
Sub Autofill2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FillRange As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set your worksheet name

On Error GoTo Errhand 'If range already is filled then go to error handler
For Each FillRange In Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'Define range in column A
        If FillRange.Cells.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then 'Check if current row is smaller than last row
            FillRange.Cells = ws.Range(FillRange.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value 'Fill the empty cells with the non empty values
        End If
Next FillRange

Errhand:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then MsgBox ("Column is already filled")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time, but if I'm not mistaken, the following should work:

```
Dim i As Integer, firstcell As Integer, lastcell As Integer
Dim currentValue As String

firstcell = 1
lastcell = 15
currentValue = ""

For i = firstcell To lastcell
    If Cell(i,1).Value = "" Then
        Cell(i,1).Value = currentValue
    Else
        currentValue = Cell(i,1).Value
    End If
Next i
```

You loop through the cells and if there is nothing in them you write the last value in them. If they contain data, you update the currentValue

Answer (score 0):

This solution using for each for more efficient looping.

```
Sub AutoFillIt()
    Dim lLastRow As Long 'Last row of the target range
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get number of rows

    Dim rngCurrentCell As Range
    Set rngCurrentCell = Range("A1") 'It will used for looping through the range

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = rngCurrentCell.Resize(lLastRow) 'Set the range working in

    Dim vLastValue As Variant ' To store the value of the last not emplty cell

    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In rngTarget 'looping through the target range
        If v = "" Then  'if the cell is empty, write the last value in
            rngCurrentCell.Value = vLastValue
        Else 'if not empty, store the content as last value
            vLastValue = v
        End If
        Set rngCurrentCell = rngCurrentCell.Offset(1) 'move to the next cell
    Next v
End Sub
```